# Pass by reference equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, oop, reference

I have two classes for the view and control of two objects from the model. The view/control classes are JPanels.
One of these objects holds a device and the other holds the configuration of this device. 
I'm initializing the class responsible for the view/control of the configurations, then I'm initializing the view/control of the device, passing the configurations in the constructor. 
The problem is when a configuration is changed in the configuration object (which is inside the JPanel that holds it), it must change in the device object as well. I wanted to pass a reference for the configuration instead of the value from the object, but I know this is not possible in java. Is there any equivalent to that or will I have to make listeners? If so, what should I use to listen to the changes made in the configuration object that is inside the respective JPanel?

Edit:
These are the variables:

```
private viewControl.JConfiguracoesParametros jConfiguracoesParametros1;
private viewControl.JEnsaiosDeCampo jEnsaiosDeCampo1;
```

And this is how I'm initializing them:

```
jConfiguracoesParametros1 = new viewControl.JConfiguracoesParametros();
jEnsaiosDeCampo1 = new viewControl.JEnsaiosDeCampo(jConfiguracoesParametros1.getConfig(), jSelecaoAspersor1.getDadosAspersor(), new PerfisRadiais());
```

What I need is the jEnsaiosDeCampo1 to always have the values from ConfiguracoesParametros1.getConfig().
In the way I have right now, if I try to use anything from the `jEnsaiosDeCampo1` that depends on the `jConfiguracoesParametros1`, I get a NullPointerException, even if I have already created the configuration object inside `jConfiguracoesParametros1`.

Comment: You can pass a single-element array of the right type, e.g. `void yourMethod(String[] someArrayYouWillUpdate)`.

Comment: You can't pass objects, only references to objects. Can you provide some code as an example, because most likely you are already doing what you want. References to objects are passed by value, not the objects the reference point to.

Comment: I'm not quite following, you're wanting an instance of your Configuration? If that's the case then you could keep a reference of something which points to the held value (quite typical of configuration systems, which usually in turn save those to a file)

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama OP isn't asking if it is pass-by-reference, (s)he is asking how to work around the fact it is pass-by-value.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, Removed. Next time more careful.

Comment: Your use-case isn't clear. Please, show us the example of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I've edited op, hope it's clearer now. PS.: I didn't put all variables from the code there (like jSelecaoAspersor1) because it's all fine with them.

Comment: (1) Shouldn’t your configuration be part of your model? (2) What do you mean by “I wanted to pass a reference for the configuration instead of the value from the object, but i know this is not possible in java.”? When you pass the configuration, you are exactly passing a reference to the configuration object. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: The object is actually passed by value as everything in java. What i wanted was to pass the actual address as in pointers. The configuration class is part of the model, but i'm instantiating it in this view/control class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just those snippets of code it’s hard to know exactly how things are supposed to work. So my suggestion may not be useful, but I’ll try:

```
private viewControl.JConfiguracoesParametros jConfiguracoesParametros1
        = new viewControl.JConfiguracoesParametros();
private viewControl.JEnsaiosDeCampo jEnsaiosDeCampo1
        = new viewControl.JEnsaiosDeCampo(jConfiguracoesParametros1, jSelecaoAspersor1.getDadosAspersor(), new PerfisRadiais());
```

The change from your code is I am passing the entire `jConfiguracoesParametros1` object to the new `JEnsaiosDeCampo` object (is that field trials or something?). In this way, the `JEnsaiosDeCampo` object has a reference to *the same* configuration parameters object, and any later change to the configuration will be visible to the `JEnsaiosDeCampo` object.

Frankly I was in doubt whether your understanding was correct when you commented

> The object is actually passed by value as everything in java.

The object itself is not passed. The *reference* to the object is passed (by value).

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a class for view and a separated one for controller

Second java always passes by reference

when you change the configuration your jpanel should inform the controller that something was changed by a method like public handleConfigChanged(config) in the controller. Then that handler shall send that information to the device and ask if to reload it.

```
public class Device{
    ...

    public void reloadConfig(config){
    ...
    }
}


public class Controller{
    ...

    public boolean handleConfigChanged(config){
    ...
    device.reloadConfig(config);
    }
}

public class View{
    ...
    private void changeConfig(config){
    ...
    controller.handleConfigChanged(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite possible using the NetBeans GUIBuilder, or at least o don't know how to do it. But i will do that in the future (but for now i have to do it that way, because i'm short on time and don't know how to proper implement the MVC model).

Comment: Pelo nome das variaveis já vi que falas portugues
aconcelho te a usares o IDE da jetBrains
podes configurar uma licença de estudante;
só com o código que puseste é dificil de ajudar

Comment: You said “Second java always passes by reference”. There seems to some disagreement here. Truth is, Java always passes by value, never by reference. For reference types (in practice, that’s all object types) the reference is passed, not the object itself, so it works much like pass-by-reference (primitive types like `char` and `int` have nothing like that, they are passed purely by value).